# Why does double type return Infinity?

Tags: c++

I made this code in C++ just to check the biggest integer **int** and **double** data types can store.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a, b;
    cin >> a;
    b = a;
    for(int c; a > 1; a = a * b)
        cout << a << "\n";
};
```

When I input 2 in the code below, the biggest integer printed is 1073741824.

I changed the code to:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

double main() {
    double a, b;
    cin >> a;
    b = a;
    for(double c; a > 1; a = a * b)
        cout << a << "\n";
};
```

The output of the second code quickly from 2 to printing **infinity**.
Why doesn't the code stop at the largest value of double? Why does it stop in the previous code?

Comment: **infinity** is a valid value for floating point numbers in almos all programming languages. However, it is almost never used.

Comment: `double main` eh?

Comment: but infinity _is_ (in some sense) the largest value of double. At least, there's +INF, and nothing is bigger than that.

Comment: @EdHeal yeah, `main` return types are getting more and more creative...

Comment: @ron I compiled both the codes using g++. Both of them are working.

Comment: No, both of them are failing in some way that hasn't actually set fire to your hair. There's a difference.

Comment: @quentin I used replace all. It works though.

Comment: @LalitKumar One of the first lessons any C++ student must learn (but sadly often doesn't) is that "working" doesn't mean correct. Many mistakes in C++ lead to *undefined behavior* which means pretty much anything can happen, including something that looks correct.

Comment: Yeah, for some value of "works" which is strictly different to _being a well-formed program with a well-defined result_

Comment: And `1073741824` isn't the largest value `int` can hold on any platform ever. (Unless there's one that has a sign bit and a parity bit, or one that has 31-bit integers, and reserves a bit pattern for integer NaN?) Your code is logically incorrect, even if you fix the undefined behavior.

Comment: @LalitKumar with a properly-configured compiler this gives [`main.cpp:5:5: error: 'main' must return 'int'`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a781ea5421df62a).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour on overflowing an `int` is *undefined*. Because of this it is not possible to elucidate the maximum possible value that can be stored in an `int`. So we have to rely on a constant that your platform will provide for you: `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` is the value of the largest `int`.

For the `double` case, technically the behaviour is also *undefined*. Although if your platform implements IEEE754, then +Inf will eventually be attained by repeated multiplication of a large enough value; a little over 1<sup>1</sup>. The largest `double` that isn't `+Inf` that your platform supports is `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`.

Finally, `main` is not allowed to return anything other than an `int`. Didn't your compiler warn you of that?

---

<sup>1</sup> The actual value of "a little" is `std::numeric<double>::epsilon()`. Acknowledge @YSC.

Comment: "[A] little" is exactly [`std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon).

Comment: @YSC - yes I think that's correct. That's possibly the smartest thing I've seen on this site this year.

Answer (score 1):

> I made this code in C++ just to check the biggest integer int and double data types can store

This is how you get the largest value you can store in a data type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std; // not in real code plz

int main() {
    cout << "largest int is " << numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
    cout << "largest double is " << numeric_limits<double>::max() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Your trial multiplication wouldn't get this right even if it was well-defined: it would just show you the last value of `a` such that the real maximum is between `a` and `a*b`.

Answer (score 0):

*Why doesn't the code stop at the largest value of double?*

Because `infinity > 1` is always true.

*Why does it stop in the previous code?*

Due to undefined behavior (or platform specific behavior) when `a` rolls over from 0x40000000 (decimal 1073741824) to 0x80000000 (decimal -2147483648) on your platform, `-2147483648 > 1` is false.